# How can I reference a variable in a variable? (powershell)

Tags: variables, powershell

My subject is probably not worded correctly.

I am working on some scripts and using the "Send-MailMessage" command. I need to have some variables in the body of the message.... How can I do this? These variables are directories, log file locations, IP addresses, etc from the script. When the script finishes or fails I need to send an email with pertinent info about the job..

$bod = "this is message please see log file at $logfilelocation"

Send-MailMessage -To user@user.com -Subject subject -From user@user.com -body $bod -SmtpServer server

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the right idea.  You just need to build up your $bod string using the variables.  A 'here' string would probably work well.  Something like:

```
$bod=@"
directory: $directory
log file location: $logfileLocation
ip address: $ipAddress
"@
```

Or are you asking how to get those values into variables?